# How to make one column of bold annotations on a heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, plot-annotations

How to format (make bold) the annotations in one particular column in a Python Seaborn heatmap? (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

Comment: Please review #3 of [Creating Effective Stack Overflow Questions](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/Creating_Effective_StackOverflow_Questions.html) and [edit] the question. If we can't copy, paste, and run the code, then it's not a **complete** [mre]. Links die. The question should include the relevant code, not a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Axes.texts` and `Text.set_fontweight`:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

glue = sns.load_dataset("glue").pivot(columns="Model", index="Task", values="Score")
ax = sns.heatmap(glue, annot=True)

col = 0
for idx in np.arange(glue.size).reshape(glue.shape)[:, col]:
    ax.texts[idx].set_fontweight('bold')
```

Output:

[image]